# can i make an array of variables with python?

Tags: arrays, variables, python-2.7

I am using Python 2.7 and Gedit.
I wrote a simple program to calculate my income.
Now I think it would be useful to house my variables in an array, is this possible?

```
# this is a test program

# my work week that I wish could hold the values of the following variables
workweek = ['sunday', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday',        'saturday']

# The variables I would like to place in an array
sunday = 0
monday = 0
tuesday = 0
wednesday = 9
thursday = 9
friday = 9
saturday = 9

print sunday + monday + tuesday + wednesday + thursday + friday + saturday

# my wage for sunday through thursday
weekdaywage = 4.25

# my wage for friday and saturday
weekendwage = 3.25

# this is my wages on thursday...
print thursday * weekdaywage

# this is coming out as an error? What can I do as a workaround
# I did a googlesearch
# All I need is a link to learning material if you don't have time to explain
print workweek * weekdaywage
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need a dictionary?

```
workweek = {
    'sunday': 0
    'monday': 0
    'tuesday': 0
    'wednesday': 9
    'thursday': 9
    'friday': 9
    'saturday': 9   
}
```

You can retrieve the value of a variable using:

```
workweek['monday']
```

This does mess up the order, if you wish to maintain the order of the days, use an OrderedDict

```
from collections import OrderedDict
p = OrderedDict([('monday', 1), ('tuesday', 0)])
```